# How do I reference another item on the same page using schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

The page https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk describes two yoga `Events` run by a `LocalBusiness`.

The `LocalBusiness` has been defined twice because it is a nested `performer` on each `Event`.

Is it possible to define an item once (e.g. the `LocalBusiness`) then link to that item from other items (e.g. the `Events`)?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Event",
          "name": "hello YOGA",
          "startDate": "2018-06-13T19:45",
          "endDate": "2018-06-13T20:45",
          "description":
            "Yoga class at Friends Meeting House (Harrogate) every Thursday.",
          "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Friends Meeting House",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "12A Queens Parade",
              "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
              "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
              "postalCode": "HG1 5PP",
              "addressCountry": "GB"
            }
          },
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "availability": "http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability",
            "price": "7.00",
            "priceCurrency": "GBP",
            "validFrom": "2018-05-01T12:00",
            "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk"
          },
          "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "ExerciseAction",
            "name": "hello YOGA",
            "description": "Small, friendly yoga class. Suitable for all abilities.",
            "exerciseType": "Yoga",
            "startTime": "2018-06-13T19:45",
            "endTime": "2018-06-13T20:45",
            "location": {
              "name": "Friends Meeting House",
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "12A Queens Parade",
              "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
              "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
              "postalCode": "HG1 5PP",
              "addressCountry": "GB"
            }
          },
          "performer": {
            "@type": "LocalBusiness",
            "description":
              "Small, friendly yoga classes. Suitable for all abilities. Strengthen body, increase flexibility and calm the mind.",
            "name": "hello YOGA",
            "email": "clare@hello-yoga.co.uk",
            "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk",
            "priceRange": "£7",
            "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
              "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
              "addressCountry": "GB"
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Event",
          "name": "hello YOGA",
          "startDate": "2018-06-07T19:00",
          "endDate": "2018-06-07T20:00",
          "description":
            "Yoga class at Beckwith Health Club (Harrogate) every Wednesday.",
          "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Beckwith Health Club",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "Beckwith Health Club",
              "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
              "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
              "postalCode": "HG3 1UF",
              "addressCountry": "GB"
            }
          },
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "availability": "http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability",
            "price": "7.00",
            "priceCurrency": "GBP",
            "validFrom": "2018-05-01T12:00",
            "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk"
          },
          "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "ExerciseAction",
            "name": "hello YOGA",
            "description": "Small, friendly yoga class. Suitable for all abilities.",
            "exerciseType": "Yoga",
            "startTime": "2018-06-07T19:00",
            "endTime": "2018-06-07T20:00",
            "location": {
              "name": "Beckwith Health Club",
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "Beckwith Health Club",
              "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
              "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
              "postalCode": "HG3 1UF",
              "addressCountry": "GB"
            }
          },
          "performer": {
            "@type": "LocalBusiness",
            "description":
              "Small, friendly yoga classes. Suitable for all abilities. Strengthen body, increase flexibility and calm the mind.",
            "name": "hello YOGA",
            "email": "clare@hello-yoga.co.uk",
            "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk",
            "priceRange": "£7",
            "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
              "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
              "addressCountry": "GB"
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
```